# Adding location data to Google Fit

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-fit

I'm writing an application in Python to add data to Google Fit.  I am successful in creating data sources and adding datasets with points for heart rate, cadence, speed, steps, etc. as well as sessions for those datasets.

I am now trying to add location data so that activities in Google Fit show maps of the activity but not having any luck with that.  Something that is unclear to me is that while all of the above items are a single data point, location is 4 data points according to https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample.

Do these 4 different items in the data point need to be named in any way, or do I just add them as 4 `fpVals` one after another in the same order as described on the above reference?  I.e. in building my array of `point`s for the dataset's *patch* operation do I just add them to the value array as such:

```
                gfit_loc.append(dict(
                  dataTypeName='com.google.location.sample',
                  endTimeNanos=p.time.timestamp() * 1e9,
                  startTimeNanos=p.time.timestamp() * 1e9,
                  value=[dict(fpVal=p.latitude),
                         dict(fpVal=p.longitude),
                         dict(fpVal=10),
                         dict(fpVal=p.elevation)]
                ))
```

where the dataset is added with:

```
        data = service.users().dataSources().datasets().patch(
            userId='me',
            dataSourceId='raw:com.google.location.sample:718486793782',
            datasetId='%s-%s' % (min_log_ns, max_log_ns),
            body=dict(
              dataSourceId='raw:com.google.location.sample:718486793782',
              maxEndTimeNs=max_log_ns,
              minStartTimeNs=min_log_ns,
              point=gfit_loc
            )
        ).execute()
```

Comment: "but not having any luck with that" what happens? Do you get an error, or do you get an OK and then no data shows?

Comment: Minor aside, not the issue: don't set start time of a location sample. The linked docs say "Because each data point represents the location of the user at the time of the reading, only the end time should be set."

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the pointer on the start time for location.  I have removed it, but I agree that it is not likely the issue.  As for what happens: everything appears to work from the perspective of the API.  I can patch in the dataset successfully -- no errors of any kind such as I have seen when I have had errors in my datasets.  I just don't get any maps showing in my activities in Google Fit.  When I try to query the dataset I added, I do get a 403, and I am aware that the API only lets one read one's own self-added location data, but I am (only) trying to read my own location data.

Comment: Haha.  Despite the documentation, when I remove the start time I do get an error: `{'message': 'StartTimeNanos required: com.google.location.sample [2022-04-11T19:50:46.628Z - 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z] [[redacted],[redacted],10.0,67.1] raw:com.google.location.sample:[redacted]'`.  Similar if I only remove the end time.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I was doing everything correctly with a small exception.  I was setting the [activity type](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types) to 95, which is defined as *Walking (treadmill)* for all activities in my prototype.  I had not gotten to allowing the user to specify the activity type and given that 95 is an indoor treadmill activity, Google Fit was simply not showing any location data for the activity in the form of a map.

Once I started using non-treadmill activity types, maps started showing up in my Google Fit activities.